# Google Maps API key in Android OpenSource project

Tags: android, google-maps, open-source, licensing

I would like to go OpenSource with my native Android App [VolcanoReport](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nbapps.volcanoreport). There is a Google Maps API key used for the MapView. I would like to know if there are security or license issues when I publish the source code containing the API key.

As far as I can see this is not in conflict with the Google [license](http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-tos.pdf) and the key cannot be misused as long as I keep my certificate used to build the app private.

Am I right or are there reasons why the code with the API key should not be published?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I can see this is not in conflict with the Google license and the key cannot be misused as long as I keep my certificate used to build the app private.

AFAIK, your analysis is correct. Anyone reusing your source code would need their own signing key and, hence, their own Google Maps API key. I have Maps API keys embedded in many of my book samples, and I am unaware of any impacts that has had.

OTOH, volcanoes might take this opportunity to accuse you of invading their privacy... :-)